# How to Add new rows programmatically to my WebDataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, infragistics

kindly let me know if possible to add multiple row when clicking button event in infragistics webdatagrid.

thanks

Comment: The Row Adding topic shows how to add a row in JavaScript: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/Current/CLR4.0/?page=WebDataGrid_Row_Adding.html

Answer (score 1):

```
DataGrid.Rows.Add("Value for Column1","Value for Column2","Value for Column3");
```

You can also...

```
DataGrid.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[CelIndex].Value = "Your Value";
```

And that's it.